# Multibyte character issue while reading from oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, multibyte

I am reading a column from database using `rs.getString() method` , the column has some multibyte data.

When retrieved through `rs.getString()` , the data get garbled and all multibyte characters appear as `??????`.

Please suggest what should be done.

I have tried using `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` , but that does not work out.

Comment: How do you check value of the string?

Comment: @axtavt I am simply assigning the result of above rs.getString() to a string type of variable... let me know if you want to know anything else.. ?

Comment: @schhajed: How do you know that result of `rs.getString()` is `??????`?

Comment: @axtavt Actually i am using the result of 'rs.getString()' to append as a text node in XML and then posting that xml to some other page and that gets processed over there.I am guessing that there is some problem while retrieving from database only..pls suggest...

Comment: Are you using the Oracle NVARCHAR2 data type?

Comment: Write a unit test that tests only this data fetching part (no XML, posting etc.).

Comment: @Puce Yes i am tracing the data that is being fetched by taking it in a string variable and printing it out... but its showing as garbled.. and further going as garbled ..too..

Comment: What kind of data are you reading? Which language? Could it be a font issue?

Comment: What is the value of your `java.util.Locale` ? What are you trying to read the String with? Can you write the string to a file and read it with an editor with which you can specify the encoding?

Comment: Create an _automated_ unit test (e.g. JUnit, not printing it out. Well, you can print it out in addition, of course), which asserts that you read what you expect to read. Test it with the data which causes the problem.

Comment: What is the database character set (SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET')?

Comment: @Puce Issue is with any kind of multibyte characters for e.g. chinese or japanese characters..so i dont think its a font issue...

Comment: @schhajed - Have you used the DUMP function to verify that the data in Oracle is actually properly encoded UTF-8 data?

Comment: Still, write a unit test to confirm that. It will help you to exactly identify the problem and to verify if it has been fixed after some code change. Afterwards it will help you to avoid a regression.

Comment: @Justin Cave ..Yes it must be because in our application , we have some ASP pages that read from the same column and display data properly..

Comment: @schhajed - Not necessarily.  It is possible to have an invalid NLS configuration that allows an ASP application to display the data correctly by bypassing character set conversion while causing corruption when a Java application does the UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html#_Toc110410550

Comment: @Justin Cave Yes i checked the DUMP function , the data is properly encoded in UTF-8 format... i guess here database part is right... but must be the way..the data is handled in java. please suggest

Comment: Any idea.. how to do it..i am still stuck with it..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the language sets installed on the machine you are trying to decode?  Can you get the data out correctly using any methods?